# Escaping <> sign from MySql table data result

Tags: php, mysql

So in my mysql table I have this data that has value of 'Some word <120>',
now when I query to fetch this data and echo ing into my view, it broke the code, and whatever code that comes after this data doesn't come out, the problem is with the <> sign, how do I escape this sign and echo it to my view ? Have tried htmlspecialchars() but it change the <120> to something else random.

Comment: What do you mean by "something else random"? ``htmlspecialchars( '<120>' )`` works exactly as intended.

Comment: @kmoser 120 is just an example, have lots of other numbers and letters with the <> sign, for example, on my browser htmlspecialchars(<SU>) returns <MM)

Comment: In my browser, ``htmlspecialchars("<SU>")`` returns ``&lt;SU&gt;`` which is exactly what it should be returning. Maybe you're dealing with a non-ASCII character set?

Comment: Is it possible that because for this layout I don't use html, body, head tag ?

Comment: My bad, somehow the data in the table changed from <SU> to <MM), no idea how. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code from this example:

```
$str ='abc <120> 890';
$str = str_ireplace(['<', '>'], ['&lt;', '&gt;'], $str);
echo $str; // abc <120> 890
```

Comment: My bad, somehow the data in the table changed from <SU> to <MM), no idea how. Thanks !